# Why are there no name ribbons on the Marauder's Map in the movie adaptation of "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince"?

Tags: harry-potter

In the film adaptation of *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* and both cinematic parts of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, why are the names on the Marauder's Map not shown in ribbons like they are in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*?

Example from Prisoner of Azkaban:

[image: Screenshot of Marauder's Map showing Peter Pettigrew's name with a ribbon surrounding it.]

Example from Half-Blood Prince:

[image: Screenshot of Marauder's Map showing Malfoy's name without a ribbon.]

Comment: Given the level of visual consistency amongst everything else in the series, its not terribly surprising this is different as well.

Comment: That would've been too difficult for, what, 1982 film animation?

Comment: 1962, actually.

Comment: I couldn't find any official confirmation, but the screenshots from HBP look very similar to the Prisoner of Azkaban credits which had the Marauder's Map design but a different font and no name ribbons. Also interesting - the HBP screenshot doesn't have a first name (presumably for simplicity); and the various screenshots from PoA often have different handwriting/fonts, even within the same film.

Comment: Presumably Harry was playing with the settings on the user interface, as teens are wont to do when they get hold of any new gadget.